# Automation of multiple apps in one session using appium in android

Tags: appium

How to automate multiple apps in one session using appium in android
 say want to automate one calculator app followed by a settings app

Comment: any updates on this? seems like the previous answers are not just to the hopes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about automating multiple apps at the same time using the same session then that is not possible since one session only can automate one app.

However, if you are talking about automating multiple apps in succession, then that is indeed possible. For example, if you have a class or project with many tests, then just run all tests in that project and as long as you have the following code in your class your Appium session should work fine after each test:

```
@After
public void tearDown(){
  driver.quit();
}
```

This method tears down the session after each test so that when the next test is going to execute it can properly re-setup the session again for the next test (whose Desired capabilities may specify a different app).

Answer (score 0):

Refer the answer in the below link.

[Automating two apps in one session in appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126999/is-it-possible-to-automate-two-apps-at-the-same-time-in-ios/43133875#43133875)