# Appium : how to handle two native apps ?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, appium

Guys does anyone know how to handle two native/ hybrid android apps in appium ?
OTP verification can be taken as an example.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/a/26836042/1746118 which should answer your question. In case you don't find what you are seeking, probably edit the same.